# Abnormal case of input in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Here is my problem:

```
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int[] firstline = new int[3];
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        System.out.print("The first line: ");
        firstline[i] = input.nextInt();
      }
      String[] array0 = new String[3];
      String[] array1 = new String[3];
      for(int lim=0;lim<2;lim++){
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        System.out.print("array"+lim+"["+i+"]: ");
        if(lim == 0){
          array0[i] = input.nextLine();
        }else{
          array1[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
        }
      }
      System.out.print(array0[0]);
```

When I compiled it, fine. But when I ran it: 
[image]

array0[0] didn't allow me to type in. 
While others worked fine. I have run in Dr.java and Intellij and they gave me
the same result

Does anyone have an explanation? Thanks first in advance.

Comment: Since you are mixing `nextInt()`, with `nextLine()`, the first `nextLine()` is wasted. You can fix this by adding `input.nextLine();` after you are done with all the `nextInt()` calls - for example after `String[] array1 = new String[3];`.

Comment: your code is working perfectly fine in eclipse IDE.

Comment: thanks a lot, i have never expected that it will be this way